# Edit Page takes me to "Page not Found" rather than "Update Route"

Tags: laravel

When i click on the Edit item Button on **"Edit Page"** the form submits and takes me to "Page Not Found" rather than **update route**..

Laravel

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.products.update', $id) }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
               {{ csrf_field() }}
               <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">
    // else form elements goes here
</form>

//route file
Route::resource('/products','ProductController');

public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
{
   return "hello";
}
```

i just wanted it to return "hello"

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the id parameter correctly in your route()

```
{{ route('products.update', [id => $id]) }}
```

Admin prefix is applied by the route, you don't need to pass it in route();

Comment: I think it's just prefix, the parameter is ok.

Comment: can you share the results of `php artisan route:list`